# When clicking save an integer in an arraylist in the sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm developing an application and on one of the screens, I need to save an ArrayList to an Integer in sharedPreferences when the user clicks to open the letter. This integer is the id of the letter.
I already have a class to configure SharedPreferences

Here is where I click to open the letter:

```
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("body", body);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
```

Comment: do you need to take the id of the letter from the body? what is body's content?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really vague.

But for all i understand, you would want to serialize your arraylist in a JsonString and put this string in the share preferences.
And deserialize it to check later.

Comment: in fact I need to feed an array with an integer whenever the user clicks to abort a letter, saving it in sharedpreferences for this letter to remain open when the user comes back on the screen.